# Unity 2019 animator preview window is extremly laggy

Tags: performance, unity-game-engine, animation, import

I have a model with 30 animations imported to it. When I open the model import settings, It is so leggy that I can't even scroll down to select any of the animations from the list. Event if I select one and play, the animation will play at very low fps. This asset worked perfectly worked with the unity previous versions ( any of 2018 versions). Soon as I upgraded to 2019 it all started. Also I can see that compiling is also very slow. It takes about 30 seconds to play the simplest scene. My laptop is i7 with 8 GB ram and 1080 GTX. Is this normal performance for new Unity ?

Comment: What is your CPU? Does it have integrated graphics? If it does, double check that your GPU is being used to run unity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It looks like Unity is running on DX11. Is there a way to check that ? I used the profiler on editor and it seems the animations are taking so much of resources  [Here is a link for profiler data](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Yv2xTyv3oDI6XVTalYKZOki2my5cjNr5?usp=sharing)

Comment: Laptop Details :- Intel(R) Core(TM) i7 7700HW CPU @ 2.80GHzm, NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1050 TI.

Comment: Doesnt sound like normal performance.. but 8gm ram is low

Comment: Your animations might be extremely heavy. Have you tried reexporting them in a lower quality setting? What is the weight of the animation file?

Comment: Same animation works perfectly with previous versions of unity. I experienced this issue in unity 2019 builds. I will check this with a 16gb ram.

Comment: Still having the same issue with that particular animation. Smaller animations works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue was fixed in 2019.2 but than it came back with 2019.3 and with LTS. It is also present in 2020.

[Original Issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/animation-window-is-really-slow-and-lagging-when-using-a-lot-of-keyframes-to-edit-animations)